# sed command works on command line but not in bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to convert text that says "6.1M" to "6.1 MB".  Simple sed command right?

($SIZE is already se to 6.1M)

```
SIZE=`echo $SIZE|sed 's/M/ MB/'`
```

This works just find on the command line.  However, when I do it as part of a bash script, I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated `s' command
```

I've tried escaping the space character with a backslash, but that didn't help.  I also tried using this syntax, both with and without escaping the space:

```
SIZE=$(sed 's/M/ MB/' <<< $SIZE)
```

Same error.  What's going on here?

Comment: Could you provide output of command `which sed` from command line and inside of script?

Comment: Your sed program is only 8 characters long. There's a mismatch between what you posted here and your error message.

Comment: Please copy 3-4 lines before and after the sed command in your script and paste it into your question.

Comment: Check your opening & closing quotes and your slashes - actually delete them and re-type them to be sure they are the characters you are expecting.

Comment: The simple fix is to say `echo "${SIZE/M/ MB}"` in pure Bash, with no `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

What version of BASH are you running?

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

The above BASH works for `SIZE=$(sed 's/M/ MB/' <<< ${SIZE});`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this line was okay.  However, I was using the SIZE variable in a later sed command, and that's where the problem was.  That command didn't have single quotes around it, and so the space character in the variable was causing the error.

Thanks to everyone for your responses!